# Omron NA User Alarms write message from string variable

Tags: vb.net, plc, hmisc

I'm trying to create a VB.NET script that writes value from existing string variable to User Alarm message. The User Alarms list updates new row as an boolean signal goes true.
The User Alarm/s is a list/db or etc. that saves alarmlogs to build in memory in HMI.
The reason why I want to write message from string, is that I've got over a 1000 alarm codes coming from Robot, which I need to see in alarm log.

I've created an user alarm object.
[User Alarms, alarm that I want to use.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Iup.png)

I'm using Sysmac studio version 1.4.

Thanks in advance

-Toni

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer for my question, you can't. I have to convert the incoming string to a specific number, which i'm monitoring in the UserAlarms -list, with this expression: ALMCODE > 99 And ALMCODE < 101, and the alarm will return when i get, ALMCODE = 100.